# Threejs cube is not showing its edges

Tags: three.js

I'm diving into the world of threejs. I have taken one of the example projects and modified it. I just added a few cube geometries with color on it. The problem is, the cube geometry shows with no edges. You cannot distinguish where the faces end, its all bleached out. Not sure if this is a lighting issue, or material issue. My code is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>three.js webgl - cloth simulation</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #cce0ff;
            color: #000;
        }
        a {
            color: #080;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="info">Simple Cabinet Box in 3D Space<br/>
    </div>
    <script type="module">
        import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';
        //import Stats from './jsm/libs/stats.module.js';
        import { GUI } from './jsm/libs/dat.gui.module.js';
        import { OrbitControls } from './jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';

        function plane( width, height )
        {
            return function ( u, v, target )
            {
                const x = ( u - 0.5 ) * width;
                const y = ( v + 0.5 ) * height;
                const z = 0;
                target.set( x, y, z );
            };
        }

        let container;
        let camera, scene, renderer;

        init();
        animate( 0 );

        function init() {
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );

            // scene
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );

            // camera
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 0, 100 );

            // lights
            //scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x666666 ) );
            const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xdfebff, 1 );
            light.position.set( 50, 200, 100 );
            light.position.multiplyScalar( 1.3 );
            light.castShadow = true;
            light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
            light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
            const d = 300;
            light.shadow.camera.left = - d;
            light.shadow.camera.right = d;
            light.shadow.camera.top = d;
            light.shadow.camera.bottom = - d;
            light.shadow.camera.far = 1000;
            scene.add( light );


            //cabinet properties
            const c_width = 24;
            const c_height = 34.5;
            const c_depth = 23.125;
            const c_left_side_thickness = 0.75;

            //Left End
            const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( c_left_side_thickness, c_height, c_depth);
            const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xC2B8B6 } );
            const left_side = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            left_side.position.set((c_width/2)*-1 + c_left_side_thickness/2,0,0);

            const right_side = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            right_side.position.set(c_width/2 - c_left_side_thickness/2,0,0);

            const geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( c_width - c_left_side_thickness * 2, c_left_side_thickness, c_depth);
            const bottom = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material );
            bottom.position.set(0,(c_height/2)*-1 + c_left_side_thickness/2,0);

            const top = new THREE.Mesh( geometry2, material );
            top.position.set(0,c_height / 2 - c_left_side_thickness/2,0);

            const cabinet = new THREE.Group();
            cabinet.add( left_side );
            cabinet.add( right_side );
            cabinet.add( bottom );
            cabinet.add( top );

            scene.add( cabinet );

            //
            // const geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );
            // const edges = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( geometry2 );
            // const line = new THREE.LineSegments( edges, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } ) );
            // line.position.set(0,100,0);
            // scene.add( line );

            // ground
            const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            const groundTexture = loader.load( 'textures/terrain/grasslight-big.jpg' );
            groundTexture.wrapS = groundTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
            groundTexture.repeat.set( 25, 25 );
            groundTexture.anisotropy = 16;
            groundTexture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
            const groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { map: groundTexture } );
            let mesh = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 20000, 20000 ), groundMaterial );
            mesh.position.y = - 250;
            mesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
            mesh.receiveShadow = true;
            scene.add( mesh );

            // renderer
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
            renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

            renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
            renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

            // controls
            const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
            controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.5;
            controls.minDistance = 100;
            controls.maxDistance = 500;

            window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize );

            if ( typeof TESTING !== 'undefined' )
            {
                for ( let i = 0; i < 50; i ++ )
                {
                    simulate( 500 - 10 * i );
                }
            }
        }

        function onWindowResize()
        {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        }

        function animate( now )
        {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }

        function render()
        {
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a lit material (like `MeshPhongMaterial`) for your boxes. `MeshBasicMaterial` is an unlit material and does not react on lights. Also using an ambient light next to your directional will make the scene look more natural.

```js
let container;
let camera, scene, renderer;

init();
animate(0);

function init() {
  container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  // scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xffffff);

  // camera
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);

  // lights
  scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.4 ) );
  
  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
  light.position.set(50, 200, 100);
  light.position.multiplyScalar(1.3);
  light.castShadow = true;
  light.shadow.mapSize.width = 1024;
  light.shadow.mapSize.height = 1024;
  const d = 300;
  light.shadow.camera.left = -d;
  light.shadow.camera.right = d;
  light.shadow.camera.top = d;
  light.shadow.camera.bottom = -d;
  light.shadow.camera.far = 1000;
  scene.add(light);

  //cabinet properties
  const c_width = 24;
  const c_height = 34.5;
  const c_depth = 23.125;
  const c_left_side_thickness = 0.75;

  //Left End
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(c_left_side_thickness, c_height, c_depth);
  const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xC2B8B6
  });
  const left_side = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  left_side.position.set((c_width / 2) * -1 + c_left_side_thickness / 2, 0, 0);

  const right_side = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  right_side.position.set(c_width / 2 - c_left_side_thickness / 2, 0, 0);

  const geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(c_width - c_left_side_thickness * 2, c_left_side_thickness, c_depth);
  const bottom = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material);
  bottom.position.set(0, (c_height / 2) * -1 + c_left_side_thickness / 2, 0);

  const top = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material);
  top.position.set(0, c_height / 2 - c_left_side_thickness / 2, 0);

  const cabinet = new THREE.Group();
  cabinet.add(left_side);
  cabinet.add(right_side);
  cabinet.add(bottom);
  cabinet.add(top);

  scene.add(cabinet);

  // ground
  const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  const groundTexture = loader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/terrain/grasslight-big.jpg');
  groundTexture.wrapS = groundTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
  groundTexture.repeat.set(25, 25);
  groundTexture.anisotropy = 16;
  groundTexture.encoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
  const groundMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map: groundTexture
  });
  let mesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20000, 20000), groundMaterial);
  mesh.position.y = -250;
  mesh.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
  mesh.receiveShadow = true;
  scene.add(mesh);

  // renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;
  renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;

  // controls
  const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI * 0.5;
  controls.minDistance = 100;
  controls.maxDistance = 500;

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

}

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.128.0/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.128.0/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: You rock!  Thank you